# Updating data on a worksheet using userform vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i am new in using excel vba, and i made a project that will show my data from woksheet to a listView. Now i want to update the data on my sheet, using a userform.

As i click any a customer on my listview and click the select button, it will get the data and it will be at the textboxes, so, i am now ready to update. But as i click the update button it has errors. These are my codes

Select button:

```
Private Sub select_Click()
Dim item As listItem

ListView1.SetFocus

Dim myindex As Integer
TextBox3.Text = Me.ListView1.SelectedItem
myindex = Me.ListView1.SelectedItem.Index
TextBox4.Text = 
Me.ListView1.ListItems.item(myindex).SubItems(1)
TextBox5.Text = 
Me.ListView1.ListItems.item(myindex).SubItems(2)
TextBox14.Text = 
Me.ListView1.ListItems.item(myindex).SubItems(3)
TextBox7.Text = 
Me.ListView1.ListItems.item(myindex).SubItems(4)
TextBox8.Text = 
Me.ListView1.ListItems.item(myindex).SubItems(5)
TextBox9.Text = 
 Me.ListView1.ListItems.item(myindex).SubItems(6)
 TextBox10.Text = 
 Me.ListView1.ListItems.item(myindex).SubItems(7)
 TextBox11.Text = 
 Me.ListView1.ListItems.item(myindex).SubItems(8)
 TextBox12.Text = 
 Me.ListView1.ListItems.item(myindex).SubItems(9)
 TextBox13.Text = 
 Me.ListView1.ListItems.item(myindex).SubItems(10)

 End Sub
```

Update button:

```
 Private Sub Update_Click()
 Dim customer As String, pickup As String, 
delivery_date As String, load As String, place As.   
String, bags As String, amount As String, status As.    
String, checkno As String, checkdate As String, note.   
As String
Dim currentrow As Long

customer = TextBox3.Text
Cells(currentrow, 1).Value

pickup = TextBox4.Text
Cells(currentrow, 2).Value = pickup

delivery_date = TextBox5.Text
Cells(currentrow, 3).Value = delivery_date

load = TextBox14.Text
Cells(currentrow, 4).Value = load

place = TextBox7.Text
Cells(currentrow, 5).Value = place

 bags = TextBox8.Text
 Cells(currentrow, 6).Value = bags

 amount = TextBox9.Text
 Cells(currentrow, 7).Value = amount

status = TextBox10.Text
Cells(currentrow, 8).Value = status

 checkno = TextBox11.Text
 Cells(currentrow, 9).Value = checkno

checkdate = TextBox12.Text
 Cells(currentrow, 10).Value = checkdate

note = TextBox13.Text
Cells(currentrow, 11).Value = note
End Sub
```

Please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. You said: *... But as i click the update button it has errors.* What errors?

Comment: `Update_Click()` has syntax errors in the declarations. Is that just here on SO, or in your actual code? (`..., place As. // String, bags as String, .., status As. // String`

Comment: You have `TextBox4.Text = ` but then go to a new line, it needs to be in one line.

Comment: `place As.  String` - don't put a  `.` after `As`.  Same with `note. As String` - no `.` after `note`.

Comment: First - you use `Dim currentrow As Long` but you don't set the variable. Second - all your other variables are excess to your code. Since you are transferring your updated text box values to your worksheet, your lines of code should look like this... `Cells(currentrow, 1).Value = Me.TextBox3.Text`

Comment: I included this code and it worked, but the problem is only the last row is updating.                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                
Dim Sh As Worksheet

Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Records")

Dim currentrow As Long


currentrow = Sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row